# Ubuntu Server Wifi and Ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless, server, ethernet

I installed the Ubuntu 16.04LTS server version, downloaded and successfully installed Edimax EW-7811Un drivers, set up a webserver and connected to my WiFi. Both LAN and WiFi interface got a (different) IP.

Everything worked fine I tried to access the server through the WiFi adapter IP address and it worked fine. Then I unplugged the Ethernet cable, restarted the whole machine and tried again to connect but with no success.

The server was up and I was able to see that he's in the network, i just wasn't able to establish a connection.
I plugged in the LAN cable and voilà I was able to reach the server over the wife IP (and obviously also over the LAN IP).

Is there any explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Please give us putput from command `route -n` when you are connected on both network, and when you are connected only on wifi. Do you use `dhcp` for interface configuration or have static ip's? "Access to server" is http, ssh, ftp ... ?

Comment: Thank you for your replay!
"Access to server" is SSH.

Here is the output with wifi and ethernet the output for only WiFi is the same
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s25
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s25
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlx74da382e1752

The ethernet  interface uses a static ip the WiFi adapter uses dhcp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is the output the same, then you have problem with default gateway witch is stay on eth card. In you case `enp0s25`. Chack again command `route -n`, when eth is disconnected. Default route must be on `wifi` interface. If not check DHCP server setting. Do you got default gateway or only `ip address` and `network mask`.

You can add in `/etc/network/if-down.d/` some script to put default gw to your wifi card `wlx74da382e1752`

Example:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/script
```

and put content

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "enp0s25 " ] || exit 0
# Return put default gw to wifi
route add default dev wlx74da382e1752
```

give `script` privilege

```
chmod 755 /etc/network/if-down.d/script
```

`if-down.d` will trigger script called `script` when `enp0s25` go `down` and put `default gw` to `wlx74da382e1752`

`wlx74da382e1752` - i guess is name of your wifi card.